# Como fazer o pseudo-elemento before funcionar?

Tags: css

Tenho o pseudo-elemento `before` mas fiz de tudo e não consigo fazer ele funcionar. A imagem não aparece de jeito nenhum.

```
section.conteudopadrao a:before{
content: url("./anuncie/pdf.png");
}
```

Há vario dias estou na busca deste funcionamento e nada funciona com o `before`.

Comment: section.conteudopadrao a::before{
content: url("./anuncie/pdf.png");
}, veja se funciona.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Comment: @BrunoCastro não funcionou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso aqui funciona para mim

```
section.conteudopadrao a:before{
    content: url("http://www.bestadsontv.com/images/facebook.gif");
}
```

Logo, a solução proposta pelo Bruno acima, deveria funcionar

> ```
> section.conteudopadrao a:before{
>     content: url("./anuncie/pdf.png");
> }
> ```

Caso não dê certo, tente assim:

```
section.conteudopadrao a:before{
    content: url("/anuncie/pdf.png");
}
```

Se continuar a ter problemas, verifique se o caminho da imagem está correto.

`EDIT`

Conforme informação de como está sua estrutura de pastas, o correto é você usar o código abaixo em seu `CSS`. ;)

```
section.conteudopadrao a:before{
    content: url("../anuncie/pdf.png");
}
```

Comment: Funcionou colocando a url completa. As outras opções não deu certo! Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @Gladison, o problema de colocar a URL completa é que caso você mude de endereço, ou mesmo a pasta onde o CSS está, o melhor é usar caminho relativo. Vamos te ajudar, em que pasta está o seu HTML/PHP e em que pasta está o seu CSS?

Comment: a imagem está na pasta `anuncie` e o css dentro da pasta `css` o arquivo `php` está na raiz do servidor.

Comment: Saquei @Gladison achava que o CSS estava no mesmo local do arquivo PHP. Modifiquei a resposta, e agora o caminho relativo deve funcionar corretamente. `PS` apenas corrigindo meu texto anterior que acabei "comendo" uma parte dele: "o problema de colocar a URL completa é que caso você mude de endereço, ou mesmo a pasta onde o CSS está, `você terá que modificar todos os arquivos que estão com URLs absolutas`, o melhor é usar caminho relativo."